# Chromebook Linux Environment ADB Debugging keeps turning off after restart

Tags: android, adb, embedded-linux, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am trying to install a APK file without Developer mode. I was told to enable ADP Debugging in Linux Environment Settings on my ACER 32-bit Chromebook.

I tried to install it using a file manager. I expected it to just download. What happened is that it said "Turn on Chrome OS Developer Mode to install apps from sources other than the Google Play Store."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.